# Training llama2 with LoRA but got a problem as follows

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, llama

I am currently facing a problem and am seeking assistance. While using LoRa to train my llama2 model, I encountered this issue. Has anyone come across this before?

> RuntimeError:
> CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

```
python -m bitsandbytes
```

> Inspect the output of the command and see if you >can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
> to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
> and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem, or should I use another method？

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.